# SD card write method crashing in AlarmReceiver

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-sdcard

I have a method that attempts to write to a text file on an SD card in an AlarmReceiver.
Before I moved it to the AlarmReceiver the method worked perfectly, but now it is crashing with the following in Logcat:

```
09-11 10:36:44.395: D/AndroidRuntime(946): Shutting down VM
09-11 10:36:44.395: W/dalvikvm(946): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception         (group=0x409c01f8)
09-11 10:36:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(946): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 10:36:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(946): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.exercise.AndroidSYSinfo.AlarmReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-11 10:36:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2126)
09-11 10:36:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-11 10:36:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
09-11 10:36:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-11 10:36:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-11 10:36:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-11 10:36:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 10:36:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-11 10:36:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-11 10:36:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-11 10:36:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 10:36:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(946): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-11 10:36:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:141)
09-11 10:36:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at com.exercise.AndroidSYSinfo.AlarmReceiver.writeSD(AlarmReceiver.java:318)
09-11 10:36:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at com.exercise.AndroidSYSinfo.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:182)
09-11 10:36:44.425: E/AndroidRuntime(946):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2119)
```

This is the relevant code:

```
  public void writeSD(Context context) 
 {
      //Toast.makeText(context,"Saving sdcardstats.txt..." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         //  
         // Write SDCard stats to file
         //
         try
           {
           FileOutputStream fOut1 = context.openFileOutput("sdcardstats.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           OutputStreamWriter osw1 = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut1);       
           osw1.write(string);
           osw1.flush();
           osw1.close();    

           }
           catch (IOException ioe)
           {

           ioe.printStackTrace();
           } //end catch


 }  // end of writeSD()
```

Comment: What is `string`? Have you checked it for null or not?

Comment: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1523

Comment: have you defined your receiver in manifest?

Comment: what is on this line:  ....writeSD(AlarmReceiver.java:318)  -- edit: two more things, 1) do you have the write to SD permission? Also you should not perform File IO in a receiver, better to start a service.

Comment: Hi, the string is not null, and the receiver is defined in the manifest, and yes I have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the manifest

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "what is on this line: ....writeSD(AlarmReceiver.java:318) -- edit:" please explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> the string is not null

Here is the source code snippet where it is failing, with line numbers:

```
140    public void write(String str) throws IOException {
141        write(str, 0, str.length());
142    }
```

The *only* way that individual statement throws a `NullPointerException` is if `str` is `null`. Hence, while you may think `string` is not `null`, your stack trace indicates otherwise.

Comment: @PhilipSheard: No, because the `NullPointerException` would have then originated in his code, not on line 141 of `java.io.Writer`.

Comment: @Commonsware: with respect, I have to disagree with you. I have printed the contents of this variable to Logcat  using System.out.println(string); and it most definitely is not null.

Comment: @Kevmeister: Then you are changing the value before your call to `write()`, setting it to `null`. Or you have multiple variables named `string` and this one is `null` in the current scope. Again, the **only** thing that can cause a `NullPointerException` on line 141 of `java.io.Writer` is if the supplied string to be written is `null`.

Comment: @Commonsware. Thanks for that - I can see the problem now but it seems to have opened up another can of worms. The string variable is assigned it's value from the onReceive() method, which has a return type of null. If I change the return type to string, Eclipse prompts me to change the method header return type to String, which then gives the message "The return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>.doInBackground(Void[])"

Comment: @Kevmeister: Since none of this references anything in your question (*what* `AsyncTask`?), and states some impossibilities (you cannot have the "return type" of a method be `null`), I do not know how to assist you further.

Comment: Ok guys thanks for all your help. I think I will tell my friend he will have to find someone else to help him with this, it's taking up way too much of my time.